# How to ignore type level in xml by XmlSerializer

Tags: xml-serialization

I have class like this:

[image: class]

(I know DataInLoop and TwoColumnData have the same properties, plz ignore that as that's not the problem.)

I made a helper function to serialize this DataList class to xml:

[image: code]

the xml result is like this:

[image: xml]
I don't want LoopData level, is it possible to remove that level?
What I want is like this:

```
<DataList>
    <Data>....</Data>
    <DataInLoop>...</DataInLoop>
    <DataInLoop>...</DataInLoop>
</DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add XmlElementAttribute to your list

```
[XmlElement("DataInLoop")]
public List<DataInLoop> LoopData { get;set; }
```

Comment: It's that easy, isn't it? Is it possible to have LoopData nodes instead of DataInLoop in Xml? I need to have more than one variable w/ same type.

Comment: You can name your nodes whatever you like. Just alter XmlElement("YourDesiredNodeName")

Comment: Thank you very much. since project schedule is very tight I had no time to think it through. question seems very naive.